# Retrieve Data in Find in set in sql using delimitter

Tags: mysql

I have a column department code which has data such as

```
SC
SS
MT
EN
```

I would like to do a find in set on the column but I am passing data of both department code and description inside the find in set
my passing data: SC - Science.
I would like to use - as delimiter and want to use the department code present in the string to be used find in set for the query.

My SQL code

```
SELECT id, dept_code FROM department WHERE dept_code IS NOT NULL AND FIND_IN_SET(dept_code, SUBSTRING_INDEX('SC - Science'), '-', 1)
```

but my query does not work.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem

Comment: Use `' - '` instead of `'-'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, dept_code 
FROM department 
WHERE 
   dept_code IS NOT NULL 
      AND 
   FIND_IN_SET(dept_code, REPLACE(REPLACE('SC - Science', '-', ','), ' ', ''))
```

See this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77c4ab/2)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `FIND_IN_SET()`.
Use only `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to get the 1st part of the string that you pass:

```
SELECT id, dept_code 
FROM department 
WHERE dept_code = SUBSTRING_INDEX('SC - Science', '-', 1)
```

The condition `dept_code IS NOT NULL` is not needed.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=30c330659059df56ac239e0eb7ac8537).